# Visual Studio in OSX: Installing Android SDK Platform-Tools v26.0.0 failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-sdk-tools, android-build, android-sdk-manager, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to compile to Android using Unity3D. The normal procedure is installing Android Studio. However I want to use Visual Studio Community (Preferences -> SDK Locations -> Android) to avoid downloading Android Studio because I do not plan to use it:

[image: screenshot]

The rest of components seems to be installed well. However the Android SDK Platform-Tools installation outputs the following error:

> Installing Android SDK Platform-Tools v26.0.0 failed
>
> Could not find a
> part of the path
> "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/package.xml".

I have been able to install it after creating an empty folder named `platform-tools` manually. Unfortunately it seems it has not been installed correctly because the folder only contains one file named: package.xml of much less than 7 Mb. Unity also output the following error:

> Android SDK is outdated
>
> SDK Tools version 0.0.0 < 24.0.0.

Workarounds seem easy (both can be downloaded from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html):

- Install Android Studio: it seems the easier and quick way, but >500Mb HardDisk space
- Install only command line tools: not so easy and quick

However I guess I'm very stubborn and curious: why could it be failing?

Comment: this seems to be a bug, but I think we have fixed it already. Which VS Mac version are you using? It would be great if you could create a bug report at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Android&component=SDK%20Manager and attach your version information and logs (especially AndroidTools.*.log), so we can investigate it. thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac Community 7.1 build 1297 @SevoKukol

Comment: Hitting the same exact problem, same build, Visual Studio for Mac Community version 7.1 build 1297.  Weirdest thing.  Creating the folder manually hits the same problem: installation just creates a single xml file in there.

Answer (score 1):

Hey mate for me it worked to create the missing folder manually.

So this folder:

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/
```

Is actually missing so if you do this:

```
$ cd /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/
$ mkdir platform-tools
```

And try to run the installer from VS UI
it should install the platform-tools package.

---

**Complement from @benjamingranados:**

Also check that the destiny folder in the "Locations" Tab is the same.

Comment: This answer worked for me partially, I had also to check that the destiny folder in the "Locations" Tab was the same (in my case, the problem is that I had the location defined as an external disk that I have no more)